# Add emoticons to twitter posts

Tags: twitter, tweets, emoticons

I have a script that opens up a tweet window for my site users. It also allows me to write the tweets for them.

But I'm wondering - how do I add emoticons to these tweets? Is there a text shorthand, that will convert to twitter emoticons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most emojis have an unicode representation; just copy the emoji you want to insert from its emojipedia page and they should display correctly when visualized on Twitter.

http://emojipedia.org/